# matrix with random components

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-variables, matrix-calculus

Is it possible to have a matrix some components being random variables? (Random variables in the statistical sense, mapping from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.)

If so, is it possible that the eigenvalues be random also, as a result of the randomness of some components?

Would you point me to some elementary source(book/lectures) on this topic? I would like to focus on the analysis (stability, eigenvalues of the expectation of a matrix, etc) of this topic.

Comment: I know very very little about this area, but seeing as you have no answers or comments within 10 hours and that the best way to get a response on the internet is to be wrong, I'll throw in my 2 cents. I have seen in the context of matrix solutions to systems of differential equations and convex optimization that you are interested in perturbing entries of a matrix or vector by a small random $\epsilon$ value to test the implementation of numerical methods because the probability that you perturbed this test vector/matrix into something "bad" should be on a set of measure zero.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I am actually interested on what matrices with random variables might mean. This would be along the lines of adaptive filters I am currently reading from a certain paper (Ikeda et al, 'Stability Analysis of Predictor Based Least Squares Algorithm'). There are some elements there such as 'expectation of a matrix' and then 'eigenvalues of the expectation of a matrix' and even the limit of all these. I am not familiar with these concepts extended from the real valued scalar matrices.

Comment: I vaguely recall that user "Did" has answered the occasional question on this site related to the eigenvalues of a random matrix. If I recall correctly, the answer given was that it is a fairly intractable problem. Aside from that, you now know everything that I know on the topic.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix